# setting up a windows a development server

Tags: sql-server, iis-7

At my last company we had a development server where the developers could create websites/tools,  upload to the development server and when setting up the host header in IIS would use *.dev.mycomany.com. Eg wiki.dev.mycompany.com.

In theory allowing us to add add as many websites as we wanted (by using a different name for *)..

All staff within the company could then access this URL's and use the tools (in house only, not externally e.g http://wiki.dev.mycompany.com)

I'm wondering how I can do something similar at my current company -

I've asked IT for:

- windows server 2008
- iis7
- sql server
- .net 4.0

Regarding the naming of multiple sites what else would IT need to configure so that I can do something similar...

or is there another way of doing this.
basically what i want to do is:

- create websites is .net
- upload to server available to internal staff only
- give an easy way for staff to access it (with a easy to remember url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - create websites is .net

Sounds like you've got this covered with the Microsoft stack you've chosen.  Not to complicate things, but you might want to look at setting up the Hyper-V role and running the server as a VM down the road to give you snapshotting and portability.

> - upload to server available to internal staff only

This could be SMB (file shares accessible to only the development team), or WebDAV, or plain FTP, although if this is for LAN access only, I really don't see the value in FTP.  IIS can be accessed remotely through `inetmgr` (IIS Manager), as well as SQL with SQL Management Studio Express.

> - give an easy way for staff to access it (with a easy to remember url)

IT needs to setup a wildcard DNS entry in the DNS Server to resolve *.dev.yourcompany.com to the IP of your new dev server.  They should know how to do this.  This will allow you to create whatever.dev.yourcompany.com as a host header entry in your corresponding IIS sites.

Comment: one requirement i forgot to mention was that i want users to be able to authenticate using active directory... is there a particular requirement needed for the server. If this server is on the network is that enough?

Comment: the server needs to be a member server on the existing Active Directory domain.  As far as Web-based Active Directory authentication, that's another question altogether.

Answer (score 1):

IIS supports multiple web sites on a single server via three different methods, assigning each site a unique IP address, assigning each site a different TCP port number or the preferred way is using the host header name

Take a look here: http://www.geekshangout.com/node/132

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting a DNS On top of it and redirecting internally a zone to it, so that new subdomains dont ahve to go through IT.